# How to get bold serif upright?

Tags: fonts, typefaces

As explained here at bullet point 6

http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/style/Mathematical-Scripts.pdf

I need to produce

bold serif italic for vectors
bold serif upright for matrices

The answer here from Mico:

[Bold, italic math (\bm) and sansmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37906/bold-italic-math-bm-and-sansmath)

Shows how the package \bm can be used to get bold serif italic, which solves the first problem.

But how can I get a bold serif upright?

I tired using \mathbf but although the font produced it upright and bold it is roman rather than serif?

[image]

Note that I am working in the bespoke document class rQUF2e which can be found in section 2 style guidelines here:

http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=rquf20&page=instructions#submission

```
\documentclass{rQUF2e}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

 $\bm{u}$ was produced using slash bm and, as desired, gives a bold (math italic) u, $\mathbf{u}}$ produced using slash mathbf produces a bold upright u but it's the roman font version of u.     

\end{document}
```

Baz

Comment: `\mathbf` seems to be what you want roman and serif mean same here, you seem to be thinking of sans-serif but that means _not_ serif (French)

Comment: OK so roman and serif upright are the same? (That is what I want bold serif upright to be precise).

Comment: Roman is a particular style of serif font (Ie a font with serifs, small bits sticking out the letters) so `\mathbf` is exactly what they intend you to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Roman" is essentially another name for an upright serif font (or viewed another way "Roman" style is the most common style of upright fonts with serifs)  so the style guide is asking you to use `\mathbf` that is,  bold roman letters.